# Amazon Api Item Search

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am using Amazon Api to search for item. I am doing a simple

```
amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords="Sachin Tendulkar", SearchIndex="All", ResponseGroup="ItemAttributes")
```

But the result is not a popular Sachin Tendulkar book or the best search I would want.

1. How can I get multiple results in Item Search ?
2. How can I get the most popular search result?

   amazon.ItemSearch(Keywords="UC Berkeley", SearchIndex="All", ResponseGroup="ItemAttributes")

gives even worse results.

Is there an option in the API that I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not getting the results you expect, adjusting the SearchIndex option to something other than "All" can often help improve the results by making a less broad search.

If you change it to "Books", do you get the expected results for "Sachin Tendulkar"?

In case that doesn't fix the problem, do you get expected results for really common searches like "Apple TV"?  And when you search for "Sachin Tendulkar" or others on Amazon.com do you the items returned by your API request show up at all (perhaps even pages down)?